# How chaining of prototypes works with RxJS in angular5?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In an angular 5 project I'm trying to deal with [`Observables`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html) but don't understand how it works when importing separated `operators`.

**Consider chaining a `fromPromise` with a `map`:**

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

with `fromPromise().map()`
return the error : `fromPromise_1.fromPromise(...).map is not a function`

**and**

```
import  'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

with `Observable.fromPromise().map()`
return the error : `Observable_1.Observable.fromPromise(...).map is not a function`

**but**

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

with `Rx.Observable.fromPromise().map()` work as expected

**like**

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

with `map.call(fromPromise(),)`

Could someone explains that ?

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pipeable operators you have to add an operator to the prototype of `Observable` to use it.

```
import  'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
```

This line adds the `fromPromise` operator to the prototype for `Observable`. You can view the source code [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.0/src/add/operator/toPromise.ts). That is why the error moved on to `map` after you added it. If you also added the one for `map` then it would likely start working for you.

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

This line will import everything which includes monkey patching all of the operators onto the Observable prototype. This will likely increase your bundle size so it should be avoided.

If you are using RxJs 5.5+ then you could use pipeable operators instead where you would do:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

autobots.pipe(map(autobot => transform(autobot));
```

Comment: Okay, everything is in the nuance of importing ``map`` with the good path: ``'rxjs/operator/map'`` import the ``map``method that you can ``call`` but ``'rxjs/add/observable/map'`` add ``Observable.prototype.map`` !